# Is java's Multithreading visible to operating system

Tags: java, multithreading

For example, I use Java to write a multi-threaded program with 5 threads. When I execute it, does the operating system (e.g. Windows 7) know that or it is just one task?

Comment: Open task manager , I guess you can see a one-one mapping !!!

Comment: The HotSpot JVM has used native threads for every OS from Java 1.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on the JVM implementation.

However, in Linux platform , **USUALLY** there is one-one mapping between java thread and native thread.

Alternatively, the JVM could chose to implement using many-one mapping ,that is many java thread are running on one single native thread. This is called [Green Thread.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads)

Comment: Does these java thread are in a lower priority as they are running on one single native thread compare to other native ones?

Answer (score 2):

Modern JVMs *tend* to use operating system threads, but it isn't specified, and the JVM is free to do otherwise.